# Django Django_Tables2 Fields

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am wanting to select only a few fields in a Django_Table2 element. I have been looking at the django_table2 website [django_table2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and I can't find much on how to limit the number of fields are used in a django_table2 element. Here is my code.

This is my Project view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Project

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Project.objects.values("id","name","jobNumber", "contractor", "assigned_to", "created_date")
    template_name = 'project/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.values("id","name","jobNumber", "contractor", "assigned_to", "created_date")

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project/detail.html'
```

This is my index.html template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for project in project_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'project:detail' project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    {% render_table project_list %}
{% endblock %}
```

How do I limit the number of fields/columns being displayed with django_tables2?

Comment: If my answer has been helpful you may want to select it as the preferred answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [tutorial](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) says "While simple, passing a queryset directly to {% render_table %} doesn’t allow for any customisation. For that, you must define a Table class."
The [API](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#Table.Meta.fields) shows that Table.Meta has fields and excludes attributes, similar to ModelForms.

Answer (score 1):

one way to go is to have the table class and add a meta exclude to remove the columns you want:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('unwanted_col', 'unwanted_col2',)
```

Then in the view logic have:

```
table = MyTable(data_list)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'table': table})
```

The imports in use in my views.py file that contains this code that are relevant to the snipits:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.config import RequestConfig
from django.shortcuts import render
```

and in the index html have the render table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The "class MyTable" part needs to go in tables.py in my project app folder correct? And the view logic part needs to go in my class IndexView correct? also do I need to include anything for this to work?

Comment: I have mine in my view.py file.  but as long as you import it in the view should not matter.  all follow up with edit to include the the imports for render and RequestConfig

Comment: Added... the imports to post.